# Excel Custom Format for Millions

Tags: excel, pivot-table

What is the custom number format when I want to convert large numbers to millions in pivot table (for example show 5 358 565 231 as 5 359 mil.)? My research suggested I should use format

> "#,###.00,,"

but it does not work for me probably since I am using the coma as a decimal separator.

Is there anything I can use instead of it?

Comment: A quick google search turned up [this](https://www.airweb.org/article/2018/01/16/formatting-numeric-data-to-millions-in-excel) and [this](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/use-a-custom-format-in-excel-to-display-easier-to-read-millions/)

Comment: Replace the commas with whatever you use as the thousands separator presumably.

Comment: @PeterT It both suggests to use the format I mention above

Comment: @Rory Thanks for the idea. I do not use them precisely as a thousand separator (I do not use any) but it worked when I replaced commas with spaces ("# ##0,0  ").